# OpenCv linking error ( gcc, windows 7 x64)

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, linker, linker-errors

I have coded OpenCv program on Linux.
Now I'm porting it to Windows ( gcc, windows 7 x64).

Includes are:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

The compilation command on the Linux (working well):

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -I. -o tester tester.c  -lopencv_core 
-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

The compilation command on the Windows is:

```
g++ -I"C:/opencv/build/include" -L"C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib"
tester.cpp  -lopencv_core249 -lopencv_calib3d249
-lopencv_imgproc249 -lopencv_highgui249 -lopencv_objdetect249 -o tester
```

The last time i was using vc12 opencv libs for mingw it was working well.

Compilation error is:

```
C:\Users\Lukasz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZXWyKF.o:tester.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefine
d reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(std::string const&)'
C:\Users\Lukasz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZXWyKF.o:tester.cpp:(.text+0x194): undefine
d reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(std::string const&)'
C:\Users\Lukasz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZXWyKF.o:tester.cpp:(.text+0x1be): undefine
d reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
C:\Users\Lukasz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZXWyKF.o:tester.cpp:(.text+0x208): undefine
d reference to `cv::VideoCapture::get(int)'

(...)

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\L
ukasz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZXWyKF.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It may be very lame question, but i need someone with fresh look. I'm just tired.

I was using awfull CMD and PowerShell... but in the MinGW shell (C:\MinGW\msys\1.0) - same error when using pkg-config:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -I. -o tester tester.c  -lopencv_core -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect `pkg-config --libs opencv`

sh: pkg-congfig: command not found
```

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenCV, but are you linking with the library which defines e.g the `cv::VideoCapture` class? Have you tried changing the order of the libraries (yes order *do* matter) you link with? Try putting e.g. `opencv_core249` last.

Comment: Yes. Command is working on linux. Yes. I was changing the order - it doesn't changed errors.

Comment: -L"C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib" - wait, you're trying to link against the visual studio libs ? impossible, imho.  "The last time i was using vc12 opencv libs for mingw it was working well." - i don't believe a word you say. you will have to *build* the opencv libs for mingw first (using cmake), then link your program against those instead.

Comment: Note that you have *different* command lines in Linux and in Windows. I'm asking about the Windows command line, which is what gives you errors. The Linux command line is irrelevant.

Comment: The problem with the MinGW shell is probably that you haven't installed `pkg-config` or that it's not in the path.

Comment: And the problem with the "bad reloc address" might by because you are mixing VC++ and MinGW libraries.

Comment: let me explain a bit more: they ditched the prebuild ming libs starting with 2.4.6, since there were too many problems with different mingw-runtimes. so even getting an older opencv version won't help you (since the runtime issue remains) and you *WILL HAVE TO REBUILD LOCALLY*